# Why does alignItems: "center" mess with the width of my cards?

Tags: html, react-native, tailwind-css

I'm building a little app in React Native, and I would like to display a bunch of cards in a FlatList. I want to put them in the center of the list but I'm running into an issue where it squishes my cards to what I assume to be 1rem. Very small anyway. I've provided a few screenshots below to illustrate what I mean:

(For easier debugging I have given everything colorful borders)

[image: Screenshot of a list of cards. They are aligned to the left and take up 80% of their container's width.]
[image: Screenshot of a list of cards. They are aligned to the middle and take up almost none of their container's width.]

In the first image all is well. The cards are the size they are supposed to be, they're just not aligned correctly. Then in the second image I have aligned them to the center of the list, but their width has decreased to almost nothing.

I am using tailwind to style my app (html for both the list and the cards provided below), but the centering of the cards is done using regular css since you can't use tailwind styling for contentContainerStyle without using a library like [tailwind-react-native-classnames](https://github.com/jaredh159/tailwind-react-native-classnames). I am a bit of a noob when it comes to html, so please let me know what mistake I am making!

Card:

```js
<View className={'my-2 w-5/6 h-36'}>
    <View className={'w-full h-full bg-white rounded-2xl p-2 shadow-md border-2 border-green-400'}>
    </View>
</View>
```

FlatList:

```js
<FlatList
  renderItem={() => <Card/>}
  contentContainerStyle={{alignItems: "center"}}
  className={'border-2 border-red-400 h-full w-full'}/>
```

Some stuff I've tried:

- Setting the width on the first View on the card to w-max or w-full. Despite being told it can take up as much space as it wants, it still chooses to only take up that little sliver in the middle.
- Adding flex-1 or flex-grow to the card does not influence the width. Strangely, this does mess with the height (the gaps between the cards disappear).
- Shrinking the FlatList to fit content, since it is already centered anyway. If I change w-full to w-fit it will, maybe predictably, simply become as thin as the cards became. What really perplexes me about this one is if I then remove the center alignment from the contentContainerStyle, the list and the cards also shrink to the thin slices I showed earlier. Adding a minimum width to the card does not solve this problem. See image below for an example of the thin list.

[image: The same list as before, but this time the container is as thin as the cards. Very troublesome]

Comment: The default is `stretch`, which obviously fills the space. When you change to `center` you lose that aspect of alignment, so the boxes collapse to the calculated size of their contents. See https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/#aa-align-items. Your question covers a lot of ground here. I'm not sure if it's ultimately about CSS, React, or Tailwind.

Comment: That is helpful, thanks! I figured out that setting a width like 72 will let me center the cards and keep their width. Perhaps it is better for me to give up on the 5/6 and just go for a static number instead.